# Cosmos DB - Use ARRAY_CONTAINS in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have collection of documents in Cosmos DB. Document can have inner array of objects. So model look like this:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public IList<InnerDocument> InnerDocuments { get; set; } 
}

public class InnerDocument
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Created { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all inner documents if at least one of them has certain type.

If I create query like this:

```
var innerDocument = new InnerDocument()
{
    Type = "foo"
};

context.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(uri, feedOptions)
    .Where(d => d.id == "sample" && d.InnerDocuments.Contains(innerDocument));
```

it translate like this:

```
SELECT * FROM root 
WHERE (root[\"id\"] = "sample" 
    AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(root[\"innerDocuments\"], {\"type\":\"foo\"}))
```

but it returns nothing, because no inner document look like this (all inner documents has also Created) so I need to add third parameter to ARRAY_CONTAINS (which tell that only part match on document is enough) so it should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM root 
WHERE (root[\"id\"] = "sample" 
    AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(root[\"innerDocuments\"], {\"type\":\"foo\"}, true))
```

My problem is that I did not figure out how to pass third parameter in linq. I also tried write IEqualityComparer, which always return true but with no effect (well efect was that I got exception..).

Do you have any idea how could I pass that param in linq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know, unfortunately there is no LINQ equivalent for the `ARRAY_CONTAINS (<arr_expr>, <expr> , bool_expr)` overload. To achieve your scenarios, for now you can use SQL query. We are currently working on a set of changes that will enable LINQ for this scenario.

Edit: the available alternative is to use the Any operator with the filters on the property you want to match. For example, the SQL filter: `ARRAY_CONTAINS(root.addresses, {"city": "Redmond"}, TRUE)` is equivalent to this LINQ expression: `addresses.Any(address => address.city == "Redmond")`

Comment: Ok, thank you - could you please add answer here when this will be possible. Thanks again

Comment: Hi there, I was wondering if there are any updates on this? I've had to hack in some wizardry for the sake of adding ", true" to the end of the query...

Comment: Hi @DavidC799 could you please show us your solution? Maybe even post it like answer so I can mark it as accepted answer for other lads with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @AdamLihm My solution was to do all the dynamic expression tree building first, then grab the SQL of that and manually concatenate on the additional piece for ARRAY_CONTAINS(<arr_expr>, <expr> , bool_expr). It's hacky, but functional and hopefully temporary.

Comment: Any does not use ARRAY_CONTAINS. My equivalent query is ```SELECT VALUE root 
FROM root JOIN (
 SELECT VALUE EXISTS(
  SELECT VALUE csn0 FROM root 
  JOIN csn0 IN root["addresses"] 
  WHERE (csn0["address"] = "Redmond")
 )
) AS v0 
WHERE v0```, although it has the same index lookup characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to retrieve all documents that have any inner document in the array with a given property value (`"foo"` in this example).

Normally, you would use `.Where(d => d.InnerDocuments.Any(i => i.Type == "foo"))`, but `Any` is not supported yet by the Cosmos LINQ provider.

Instead, you can use this construct as a work-around:

```
context.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(uri, feedOptions)
    .Where(d => d.Id == "sample")
    .SelectMany(d => d.InnerDocuments.Where(i => i.Type == "foo").Select(i => d));
```

According to [this thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/11503872-support-linq-any-or-where-for-child-object-collect) Microsoft has recently started working on a real `Any` feature for the Cosmos LINQ provider.

Comment: Any is supported now, however, it appears to be several orders of magnitude slower that using inline SQL.

Comment: @Lance where did you find Any to be supported for Cosmos?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was slightly more of a hack than a solution, but it works temporarily until the full functionality for .Any() exists.

I use Expressions to dynamically build the Where predicate for my documents, allowing me pass in a CosmosSearchCriteria object which has a list of CosmosCriteria objects as below:

```
public class CosmosCriteria 
{

    public CosmosCriteria()
    {
        ContainsValues = new List<string>();
    }
    public CosmosCriteriaType CriteriaType { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
    public ConvertedRuleComparitor Comparitor { get; set; }
    public DateRange Dates { get; set; }
    public List<string> ContainsValues { get; set; }
}
```

This allows me to query any property of the Contact model by essentially passing in the PropertyName and PropertyValue.

I haven't looked into the other workaround in here to see if I can make it work with my expression tree building, at the minute I can't afford the time to investigate.

```
    public async Task<CosmosSearchResponse<Model.Contact>> 
    GetContactsBySearchCriteriaAsync(int pageSize, long companyId, 
    CosmosSearchCriteria searchCriteria, string continuationToken = null)
    {
        var collectionName = CreateCollectionName(companyId, Constants.CollectionType.Contacts);
        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = pageSize };
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken))
        {
            feedOptions.RequestContinuation = continuationToken;
        }
        var collection = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                Configuration.GetValue<string>(Constants.Settings.COSMOS_DATABASE_SETTING),
                collectionName);

        IOrderedQueryable<Model.Contact> documents = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Model.Contact>(
            collection,
            feedOptions
        );

        documents = (IOrderedQueryable<Model.Contact>)documents.Where(document => document.deleted != true);
        bool requiresConcatenation = false;
        foreach (var criteria in searchCriteria.Criteria)
        {
            switch (criteria.CriteriaType)
            {
                case Constants.CosmosCriteriaType.ContactProperty:
                    // This is where predicates for the documents.Where(xxxx) 
                    // clauses are built dynamically with Expressions.
                    documents = AddContactPropertyClauses(documents, criteria);
                    break;
                case Constants.CosmosCriteriaType.PushCampaignHistory:
                    requiresConcatenation = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        documents = (IOrderedQueryable<Model.Contact>)documents.AsDocumentQuery();

        /*
            From this point onwards, we have to do some wizardry to get around the fact that there is no Linq to SQL
            extension overload for the Cosmos DB function ARRAY_CONTAINS (<arr_expr>, <expr> , bool_expr).
            The feature is planned for development but is not yet ready. 
            Keep an eye on the following for updates:
                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412557/cosmos-db-use-array-contains-in-linq
                https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/11503872-support-linq-any-or-where-for-child-object-collect
        */
        if (requiresConcatenation)
        {
            var sqlString = documents.ToString();
            var jsonDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(sqlString); // Have to do this to remove the escaping
            var q = (string)jsonDoc.query;
            var queryRootAlias = Util.GetAliasNameFromQuery(q);

            if (queryRootAlias == string.Empty)
            {
                throw new FormatException("Unable to parse root alias from query.");
            }

            foreach (var criteria in searchCriteria.Criteria)
            {
                switch (criteria.CriteriaType)
                {
                    case Constants.CosmosCriteriaType.PushCampaignHistory:
                        q += string.Format(" AND ARRAY_CONTAINS({0}[\"CampaignHistory\"], {{\"CampaignType\":1,\"CampaignId\":{1}, \"IsOpened\": true }}, true) ", queryRootAlias, criteria.PropertyValue);
                        break;
                }
            }

            documents = (IOrderedQueryable<Model.Contact>)Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Model.Contact>(
                collection,
                q,
                feedOptions
            ).AsDocumentQuery();
        }

        var returnValue = new CosmosSearchResponse<Model.Contact>();
        returnValue.Results = new List<Model.Contact>();

        Console.WriteLine(documents.ToString());

        var resultsPage = await ((IDocumentQuery<Model.Contact>)documents).ExecuteNextAsync<Model.Contact>();
        returnValue.Results.AddRange(resultsPage);
        if (((IDocumentQuery<Model.Contact>)documents).HasMoreResults)
        {
            returnValue.ContinuationToken = resultsPage.ResponseContinuation;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Hope this helps, or if someone has a better way, please do tell!

Dave